# Unable to set device owner through programmatically

Tags: android, device-owner

I tried to execute the following code to set my app as a device owner. I can't use ADB because I have more than 10K android-9  non rooted devices. So, Need to do this programmatically.

```
   String name = AdminReceiver.class.getName();
   if (name.startsWith(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID)) {
           name = name.substring(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID.length());
   }
   final String command = "dpm set-device-owner " + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + '/' + name;
   Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
   Log.d(TAG,"RETURN VALUE:"process.waitFor();
```

process.waitFor() always return 1.

Answer (score 4):

> Need to do this programmatically

Fortunately, that is not possible, for blindingly obvious security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Use QR Enrollment instead!

You can generate a QR Code which contains a URL for your Device Owner package. Then you can scan this code in the factory setup process of the device.

[See the documentation here](https://developers.google.com/android/management/provision-device#using_qr_codes)

The Data in the QR Code would look something like this:

```
{
    "android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_COMPONENT_NAME": "com.google.android.apps.work.clouddpc/.receivers.CloudDeviceAdminReceiver",
    "android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_SIGNATURE_CHECKSUM": "I5YvS0O5hXY46mb01BlRjq4oJJGs2kuUcHvVkAPEXlg",
    "android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION": "https://play.google.com/managed/downloadManagingApp?identifier=setup"
}
```

Simply replace the information with your own device owner package information. After scanning, the device will download, install, and set up the device owner.

---

If you become an EMM Partner with Google, you can even do Zero-Touch-Enrollment by getting preconfigured android devices from the manufacturers. But Google stopped approving requests for custom device policy managers and you must use the Android Management API now.

---

Footnotes

- [Instructions on how to scan the QR Code](https://developers.google.com/android/management/provision-device#qr_code_method)
- [Device Admin Developer reference for streamlining this into the device admin app](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin)