# Unable to set an application as a Device Owner (DO) using ADB shell on Android 10 devices

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, device-owner

Using the ADB command to set a chosen application as a Device Owner works on Android 9 and lower Samsung devices. It does not work on our Android 10 phones (Samsung S9 and S10) but it works on Android 10 Google Pixel phones. We made sure to remove any accounts from the devices and tried factory reset too. The command we use is: adb shell dpm set-device-owner /. The error we receive is always the same:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't set package ComponentInfo{com.example.xxxx/.DevAdminReceiver} as device owner.
        at com.android.commands.dpm.Dpm.runSetDeviceOwner(Dpm.java:204)
        at com.android.commands.dpm.Dpm.onRun(Dpm.java:115)
        at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:56)
        at com.android.commands.dpm.Dpm.main(Dpm.java:41)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:339)
```

Comment: Are you able to set it from code as usual?

Comment: Hey @MatPag, using Runtime.getRuntime().exec makes no difference (we're on unrooted devices though). Is that the code you had in mind?

Comment: Might be because Samsung sets it's own device owner in the setup process. You might have luck using QR Enrollment but it will be a pain to do active development. [QR Enrollment example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61346681/2232127)

Comment: @Android did you find the cause? or some solutions?

Comment: DO cannot be set on devices that have been previously rooted